# Bootstrap и БЭМ. Как совмещать?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, dom, бэм

Работодатель требует писать код по методологии БЭМ. Почитала про БЭМ и вроде бы и все просто, но в то же время не понятно)

Нужноли что бы элементы (блоки сетки бутстрапа) были без класса БЭМ? только `.container` `.row` ?

Например:

```
<body class="page">
<div class="page__head-line"></div>
<header class="page__header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="header-top-bar">
                <div class="header-top-bar__search col-md-4">

                </div>
                <div class="header-top-bar__logo col-md-4">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <h1 class="logo__text"><a href="#">Taffle</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="header-top-bar__quick-access col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navigation">
                <ul class="menu col-md-12">
                    <li class="menu__item">Home</li>
                    <li class="menu__item">Shop</li>
                    <li class="menu__item">Promo</li>
                    <li class="menu__item">About</li>
                    <li class="menu__item">Blog</li>
                    <li class="menu__item">Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="page__content container"></div>
<footer class="page__footer container"></footer>
```

Или правильнее будет такой вариант?

```
        </div>
        <div class="header-top-bar__logo col-md-4">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1 class="logo__text"><a href="#">Taffle</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-top-bar__quick-access col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navigation row">
        <ul class="menu col-md-12">
            <li class="menu__item">Home</li>
            <li class="menu__item">Shop</li>
            <li class="menu__item">Promo</li>
            <li class="menu__item">About</li>
            <li class="menu__item">Blog</li>
            <li class="menu__item">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="page__content container"></div>
<footer class="page__footer container"></footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Стили бутсрапа можно вообще не трогать, используй их как в первом примере. А все остальное верстаешь в стиле БЭМ.

А именно от бутстрапа что требуется? Если нужно только grid, то есть проект на бэм, bem-grid называется.